# Keeping Class Info In Database

Tags: c++, wt

I have several classes (same base class) and only some users allowed to instantiate some. I need to keep allowed classes for a user in a database.

I definitely need some suggestions. Because I think, I should not need to have a list of class names as a string in database and instantiate them in a condition of string comparison. It just does not feel right to me.

Typical scenario is 
1. Calling GetAllowedClassesToInstantiate(user) [From Database] 
2. Instantiate those classes

Do you have any suggestions?

Regards,
Burak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a data structure like this:

```
class BaseClass;

std::map<std::string, std::function<BaseClass*()> Factories;
```

and initialize it in the following way:

```
class One : BaseClass { ... }

void init() {
    Factories["One"] = [](){ return new One(); }
}
```

Basically it will serve as a lookup `ClassName -> Constructor`.

Keep allowed class names in the database. After you retrieve it, present it to the user and when he chooses an option, look up the proper constructor wrapper function in `Factories` and use it to instantiate the selected class.

Make sure to keep the database entries up-to-date with the entry keys in`Factories`.

*(I've used some C++11 in the code sample. You can do the same in C++03 with a bit more code, without the lambda expression and `std::function`, but the idea stays the same.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can do it using boost I guess.